# Can we nest a DomDocument object in another DomDocument Object?

Tags: php, dom, nested, domdocument

I got a simple question here, but it is confusing me a lot..

**Can i nest a dom Document objective in another Dom Document object?**

My answer to the question is NO, should be one tree with child node , not a tree with child trees..It is only my answer and i am not expert,

I need the exact answer...Am I thinking right about nesting?

Explain Please...

Comment: Did you answer your own question???

Comment: I don't know for 100% sure, but I'm pretty certain that what you suspect is indeed true (that you can't nest DOMDocument objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the DOM spec:

> [the `Document` interface] is the root of the document tree [(source)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#i-Document)
>
> The root node is a node that is not a child of any other node [(source)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/glossary.html#dt-root-node)

I take this fairly clearly to mean that, according to the DOM spec, a `DOMDocument` object (which implements DOM's `Document` interface) cannot be nested within another. I'm not certain, but I'm fairly sure the PHP developers would not have implemented this in any other way.